# c# - windiff style vertical line

Tags: c#, winforms

Diffing tools such as windiff or beyond compare has a vertical line on the left side that shows all places where old and new files are different.

How do I achive this in c# winform application?

Comment: I've never heard of a ready-made component for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a component that paints line segments aligned with the editbox or some other form of text to do that.